# How can I split a large file on Windows?

Tags: windows-xp, 7-zip, text-editing

Is there a tool to split large text file (9 GB) into smaller files, so that I can open it and look through?

Is there anything usable from the command line that comes with Windows (XP)?

Or what's the best way to split it? Can I use [7-Zip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7-Zip) to create separate volumes and then unzip one of them separately? Will it be readable or does it need all the other parts to unzip into the big file again?

---

I put together a quick 48-lines Python script that splits the large file into 0.5 GB files which are easy to open even in [Vim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_%28text_editor%29). I've just needed to look through data towards the last part of the log (yes, it is a log file). Each record is split across multiple lines so [grep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) would not do.

Comment: I see you edited to mention grep. Do you have cygwin or unxutils installed? You could have used `grep -n` with `head` and `tail` to see chunks of the file. Example, `grep -n "something" file.txt` returns `95625: something`. You want to see that line and 9 lines below it for a total of 10 lines: `head -n 95635 file.txt | tail -n 10`.

Comment: I notice you solved your problem, If you're still around, could you post the solution so others might benefit?

Comment: This has been discussed in much detail at [SO][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159521/text-editor-to-open-big-giant-huge-large-text-files

Answer (score 50, accepted):

There is a freeware Windows file splitter called **HJSplit**.

It is available [here](http://www.hjsplit.org). The website claims it can split files of any type and size, but 9 GB is a **big** file.

Comment: According to the publisher, it supports splitting of files "over 100 Gigabytes"

Comment: I was able to use this program to split a large file into smaller pieces, but only by size (kB or MB). It does not respect lines, so it's not very useful for splitting log files. It's also very slow.

Comment: HJSplit works so ugly... It does not work with 5Gb+ files. The biggest part of file just losing at all. Chunck peases counter nofuses after 999, and something else failes if use bigger peases

Comment: On 64bit systems it only works with a GUI in Windows. If you want to automate things, this is not a solution

Comment: hjsplit is a dead URL

Comment: @SergePavlov Perhaps it went down for a while. It's up today (2021 5 March)

Comment: After clicking around on that site for far too long I found it available here: https://hjsplit.en.softonic.com/

Answer (score 44):

The [GNU Core Utils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/) package (available [here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm) for Windows) includes the Split utility.

The `--help` documentation is as follows:

```
Usage: split [OPTION] [INPUT [PREFIX]]
Output fixed-size pieces of INPUT to PREFIXaa, PREFIXab, ...; default
size is 1000 lines, and default PREFIX is `x'.  With no INPUT, or when INPUT
is -, read standard input.

Mandatory arguments to long options are mandatory for short options too.
  -a, --suffix-length=N   use suffixes of length N (default 2)
  -b, --bytes=SIZE        put SIZE bytes per output file
  -C, --line-bytes=SIZE   put at most SIZE bytes of lines per output file
  -d, --numeric-suffixes  use numeric suffixes instead of alphabetic
  -l, --lines=NUMBER      put NUMBER lines per output file
      --verbose           print a diagnostic to standard error just
                            before each output file is opened
      --help     display this help and exit
      --version  output version information and exit

SIZE may have a multiplier suffix: b for 512, k for 1K, m for 1 Meg.
```

For example, to split input.txt into 100Mb chunks, only splitting at the ends of lines,

```
split input.txt -C 100m
```

will give you output files named xaa, xab, xac, etc.

Comment: for example git msys download includes the utility as well.

Comment: [Cmder](http://cmder.net/) is amazing for this

Answer (score 32):

One can use [7-Zip](http://7-zip.org/download.html)  to create segments of text file in certain size (e.g. 100 MB segments out of 1.5 GB log file).

The Key options are 
- Use "Store" as opposed to "Compress"
- Use "Split to volumes"

You should be able to see text in .001 (.nnn) files.

[image]

Comment: The attached image is perfect!

Comment: Good alternative, without the need to install anything (most people have either 7zip or WinRar). I tried the different formats, and they all only store the header in the first file, the rest have no headers. The smaller headers are with zip and 7zip formats. With WinRar you can do the same thing, headers are also small, but it adds them to every file, so that's a little more effort if you need too many parts.

Answer (score 15):

Another is [GSplit](http://www.gdgsoft.com/gsplit/) - according to their site it can split very large files (larger than 4 GB <-- since they crossed the 4 GB limit, I guess they can do 9 GB as well).

But, another thing—you say you want to split it into smaller parts, so you can open it up and look at it. That sounds like a very big file, perhaps a log file.

In any case, for opening large text files, may I recommend [EmEditor](http://www.emeditor.com/). They claim themselves it can open very large files (up to cca. 250 GB), and I've used it in the past for files up to 2 GB. But in any case, I think it may be a better solution than splitting.

Comment: I've just tried out GSplit. It works, albeit through a confusing interface, but it doesn't offer any way to only split at a linebreak - for splitting ASCII data files, therefore, it's not too useful as the split will be half way through a line.

Comment: @Flyto It actually **is** possible to split by line if you choose "Split After Occurrence Number" under the `Pieces > Type and Size` menu. You then choose the number of lines and the line delimiter in hex. By default it has Windows format CR+LF (`0x0D0x0A`).

Comment: @nullability thanks - I wouldn't have thought of that. But, I found a much simpler solution through the GNU "split" utility - see my new answer :-)

Answer (score 9):

Check out [Large Text File Viewer](http://www.swiftgear.com/ltfviewer/features.html), it's great for things like this. Most archivers and splitters will separate the file into pieces which cannot be used to read each piece of data independently and properly, you need to extract them all to get the file back.

[image]

Large Text File Viewer is free and portable.

Comment: The link seems to be broken, this works as of now: http://www.softpedia.com/get/Office-tools/Other-Office-Tools/Large-Text-File-Viewer.shtml

Comment: The original (or edited?) link is working now; I'd take that link over softpedia any day!

Also, just tried LTFViewer, and it's awesome, opened an 818MB file that even Notepad++ complained about opening.  Not much in the way of editing features, but once I'd viewed the logs in LTFViewer, `echo. > myfile.txt` resolved the 818MB logfile issue :D

Comment: LTFViewer is realy great ( i'm using it to ), but there's an limit. I tryed to open an 3GB SQL file with it, but it freezes. Mayby i didn't have enough patience or something...

Comment: LTFViewer worked very well for me. I used it on a (relatively) smaller file, only 750MB, but it opened it in under 5 seconds.

Comment: You can download it from the internet archive:  http://web.archive.org/web/20151019115332/http://swiftgear.com/

Comment: Worked well for me for 1.7GB, very fast. I have 48GB RAM on the server PC, so don't know if it works well with limited RAM.

Answer (score 8):

You can use 7-Zip itself to split the files. (You can save as a .zip or .7z format.) When you go to create the archive there is an option called "Split volume, bytes". Just select how large you want the chunks.

And yes, you can unzip them individually if you wish.

[image: Split files in 7-Zip]

Comment: I don't think you can unzip them individually, you always need to start from the first file. What you can do is what other answer states: use compression level "store", so the file goes directly into the zip or 7zip file. Only the first file will have the header that you will need to remove.

Answer (score 4):

There's an online tool that splits text files if anyone is looking to split files quickly. http://www.textfilesplitter.com.

Works great for me. And splits files respecting lines which is what I was looking for. It also says it's all HTML5 client side so it's safe to use. I'm not sure how big it can go but I think it depends on your machine's ram.

Comment: Are you really suggesting to upload a 9 GB file to have it splitted in your browser?? Really??

Comment: @spaghettidba: He says it works *client side* using HTML5.  If that's the case, than it does not need to be uploaded.  I admit, I had the same reaction as you when I first read the answer, though.

Comment: Yep, I split 100+ MB in just a couple of seconds. No way it could have uploaded worked and downloaded that fast.

Comment: Worked for me with a 141mb file. Was quick and exactly what I was looking for, amazing!

Answer (score 0):

The idea of seeing part of the file before deciding what to do with it is for me the best option.

[The Large Text Viewer App](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/large-text-viewer/9nblggh4mcm8?activetab=pivot%3Aoverviewtab) can be installed on Windows through the Microsoft Store and it offers an option to cut the file in chunks of  size.
It may well be that it uses the same editor previously mentioned (behind the scenes), but the option to install it from a known source is better IMHO than the alternative links offered.
It worked great for me.

The only issue if splitting by size is that it not necessarily breaks the file at a good place, so you may have to edit it to capture the exact content you want.

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to include the name of the app, so it can be indexed and found by search.

Answer (score 0):

Splitting files is also a function of [Total Commander](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_Commander), the tool I can't do my work without.

Get your 30-day trial here: https://www.ghisler.com/
Licenses are dirt-cheap, concurrent and permanent.

In Total Commander, highlight the file you want to split. Select [file][split file] from the menu. In the pop-up, select your target-directory and "bytes per file".
Choose from: 1.44 MB, 1.2 MB, 720 K, 360 K, 100 MB, 250 MB, 650 MB or 700 MB.
Press <kbd>OK</kbd> and watch the magic happen...

Answer (score 0):

I have found the program ffsj very useful.  There doesn't seem to be a homepage around currently.  But there is a download page [here](https://the-fastest-file-splitter-and-joiner.en.softonic.com/).  Be careful with the download clicks, as they try to get you to download additional software, as well.

Comment: Why would we trust *softonic.com*?

Comment: @PeterMortensen, Yes, indeed, you should be very careful and skip if you don't feel comfortable.  This is, by far, not a recommendation for softonic.com.  But at the time of my answer, it seemed to be only the site that had a valid download link for the software.