# How can I archive a 30 GB file?

Tags: dvd, zip, archiving, burning

I have a 30 GB zip file containing an archive of digital materials available in the school library that I want to burn to DVD.  Of course, 30 Gb is far too large for a single DVD and the content is already zipped.  I'm open to ideas, but leaning towards suggestions that will help me automatically spread the file over multiple DVDs, including a simple program to stitch it back together again later.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest solution is probably to just split the file, then re-concatenate it before unpacking.

There are many file splitting programs available. On Linux/Unix, `split -b` will work fine; on Windows, see e.g. [How to split large file on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/94083/how-to-split-large-file-on-windows) .

That said, this has the disadvantage that you need to get all the DVDs and re-concatenate the file on disk before you can read anything. Maybe another approach is better?

Options would be:

- put everything on a portable harddrive
- create a multi-volume zip archive
- zip parts of the data individually to create multiple smaller zip files

Comment: I like the portable hard drive idea.  We have a small number of those lying around I could put in an enclosure and then put away somewhere safe. Probably last longer, too.  I could even pre-unzip the files.

Answer (score 2):

You want Disc Spanning, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disc_spanning.

I haven't used this since my 3.5" disk days but it is still valid. The wiki article has links to a freeware and an open source program that will span DVDs.

Answer (score 2):

[7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html) on Windows supports spanning. Simply select "4480M - DVD" from the "Split to volumes, bytes" dropdown in the "Add to Archive" window.

Answer (score 0):

write your dvd with the program toast titanium pro v 10 , the toast program when selecting the type of dvd in toast program , select that kind you have (for example dvd 5 4.7 GB) , the toast automaticlly split your file for some dvd , after burning you use your dvds , automatically a program run and ask you to save your file or files on hard disk , after reading first dvd ask you for others. that kind of writing works in windows and mac . it's perfect , no matter your file is zip or others files .

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to @sleske's reply, I'd copy the 30Gb file to more than one hard drive and store in different places, just in case one gets trashed.