# How can I split a large SQL file into smaller chunks?

Tags: file-transfer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to split large file on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/94083/how-to-split-large-file-on-windows)

I have a 100MB SQL file which my host won't let me upload all at once (2MB per upload).

The database is on a different server so I can't use SSH. I'm stuck with phpMyAdmin.

Is there any program that can split a 100MB SQL file into 2MB chunks?

Comment: Voted to migrate to Superuser, as this isn't a development question.

Comment: Ohh man without ssh this going to be hard. Have you tried zipping it? I know it won't get you to 2MB but hopefully close.

Comment: If a zip will do, several zipping apps can split files into custom sized chunks.

Comment: @Mehper Might be not that trivial using SQL.

Comment: Upload your files by zipping them into multiple archives.  Then, you can write a simple script using the [PHP Zip Library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php) (included by default) to unzip them.  Alternatively, you could split the file on your computer (just do a binary split), and use PHP to re-join the files.

Comment: Isn't an SQL file simply a text file containing a list of `create table` and `insert` statements? If so surely it is amenable to splitting at statement boundaries in a text editor or script?

Answer (score 2):

You can give this script a try, it has helped me out a couple of times:

http://www.ozerov.de/bigdump/

Altho it does not always work as expected.