# Reading a .reg file exported from an old install?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-registry

I formatted my computer (Win7->Win7 fresh install) a few months ago, and before I did so I exported the registry to a file (Along with the usual folders) just in case. Now I need to get at some entries in that file, but I'm at a loss as for how.

Is there some way to read a big .reg file without importing any of it?

Comment: You exported the entire registry Hive?  You just right click on the file and select edit or open it in any word processor of your choice.

Comment: It's 600+mB and glogg doesn't want to read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

REG files are regular text files. You can open small REG files with Notepad, but full registry exports can be hundreds of megabytes in size and Notepad won't be able to handle them. You can use [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) or [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/) to view them.

REG file structure is [described](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Registry#.REG_files) on Wikipedia.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned: 
"File is too big to be opened by Notepad++"

Comment: Apparently Sublime Text worked, thanks :). I had tried Notepad++ at first and it didn't work, so I looked for alternatives to open big files and found Glogg, and since that didn't work I assumed it was a binary file. Sublime is incredibly slow to search, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's plain text, just split the file into parts.  Previous question on this:

[How to split large file on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/94083/how-to-split-large-file-on-windows)